# Can you change this code into jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need help to change pure javascript code into jquery code

```
document.getElementById('type').onchange = function (){
        if(this.value == "Student"){
            $("#cls").prop({disabled: false});
            $("#sec").prop({disabled: false});
            $('.cls').show();
            $('.sec').show();
            }
            else{
                $("#cls").prop({disabled: true});
                $("#sec").prop({disabled: true});
                $('.cls').hide();
                $('.sec').hide();
            }
    }
```

Comment: That already is jQuery mostly? Where in particular do you have a problem?

Comment: When i use same code in to same js file it does not work in different html page.

Comment: @KhanSunny What do you mean by “it does not work”? That’s not a helpful description. Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve] of _that_ problem, and ask about _that_. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Comment: So you don't have a problem with this code not using enough jQuery at all? Please post the markup of your two html pages, so that we can see how it is supposed to work and where it does not work - make a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is mostly jQuery. Having said that you can reduce it a bit.

```
$('#type').on('change', function (){
    if (this.value == "Student"){
        $("#cls, #sec").prop({disabled: false});
        $('.cls, .sec').show();
    } else{
        $("#cls, #sec").prop({disabled: true});
        $('.cls, .sec').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: @Xufox Or just `this.value`, which is faster and shorter.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, fixed!

Comment: Can and should be reduced even more: `var isStudent = this.value == "Student"; $("#cls, #sec").prop("disabled", !isStudent); $('.cls, .sec').toggle(isStudent);`

Comment: @Bergi _But it’s not enough jQuery!_